# Add detailed info about table

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, cloudscribe

I'm using the Cloudscribe.Web.Pagination [TAG HELPER] https://www.cloudscribe.com/cloudscribe-web-pagination in my web application. I would like to add the detailed information that usually appears on all sites to my table similar this:

[image]
To do this (I haven't found any examples) I thought to extend the cloudscribe.Pagination.Models class by adding properties needed to transfer the information from control to view.
How can I do this? I need an example because I'm new in MVC